# Windows Explorer Keeps On Crashing

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

I'm lost...

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.
My Pc is up to date(windows updates) and I've used Winutilities to scan my registry.

My explorer.exe keeps on crashing. Just randomly it seems.
I don't even need to be doing anything particular.

I do have experience with pc in general as I'm a software developer.
I know you will require additional info, but i don't know what, so just leave a comment and I'll update.

**Additional info**

I think i should also mention that **explorer** is the only app that crashes on my pc.

The crash report i got now:

```
Description:
A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

   Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   AppHangB1
  Application Name: explorer.exe
  Application Version:  6.1.7600.16450
  Application Timestamp:    4aebab8d
  Hang Signature:   0a1b
  Hang Type:    16897
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    7177
  Additional Hang Signature 1:  0a1bdae38ae7300761c516c4416d992c
  Additional Hang Signature 2:  1c51
  Additional Hang Signature 3:  1c518a49cc7d37652d26c521e96f66c2
  Additional Hang Signature 4:  521e
  Additional Hang Signature 5:  521e607ec26a72aab4ae5a7126916ef3
  Additional Hang Signature 6:  e5e3
  Additional Hang Signature 7:  e5e3ca31dad607fa7b858ff5ea5c0fa9
```

Running `scf /scannow` returns: `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations` so no probs there

I finally ended up formatting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that **Winutilities** is the culprit,
And during some cleaning it may have cleared a registry entry and messed with explorer :S
Usually Explorer.exe is a bad to repair so:

1-If you can, restore registry entries from Winutilities usually these applications keep a backup somewhere.

2-Check system file [Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)

3-If this is not working you can try Through [System Recovery Options at Boot](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/700-system-restore.html) from your Original Windows 7 Disk or any Windows 7 64bit Recovery Disk.

4-If this is not working and you want to keep your Settings,account,Appdata
 you can try a Windows 7 [installation repair](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)

Thatś the best you can do before clean re-formatting

Comment: Running scf /scannow returns: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations so no probs there. Winutilities i used to attempt to fix the problem, the crashes had already occurred before that. I'll try a system restore to see if that solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

do you happen to have any software installed that integrates with explorer?
I'm thinking TortoiseSVN, TortoiseGit (especially that last one does crash my explorer.exe from time to time)

Comment: Not one of those two, but i do have: unlocker, teracopy, winamp, notepad++, Trend Micro Titanuim Maximum Security. But also explorer does not specifically crash when I'm using any software, i could be doing nothing and it would still crash

Comment: yeah but that's the same in my case: not doing anything yet crashes. When did the crashes start? after you made some change to software/configuration? You can always uninstall everything listed and see what it does, but I reckon that's not such a nice solution.

Comment: The crashes started shortly after a clean install of windows, the problem is i can't just format and hope it goes away. This is my work machine. I can't pin point an exact start location, so I'm hoping to get a solution that doesn't require a format.

Comment: sorry to hear that. Is system restore an option maybe? that's basically like uninstalling everything but better..

Comment: a system restore could be an option. I'll try it and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your memory?
http://www.goldmemory.cz/news.php
http://www.memtest86.com/

And also open a command line and type this: `sfc /scannow` (it'll check the integrity of the "important files".)

Comment: I have tried `sfc /scannow` before and will try again but the first time i tried it everything was fine. my memory has also been tested and nothing was wrong

Comment: How did you test your memory?

Comment: using memtest86...

Answer (score 0):

When explorer.exe crashes, it will generate a .dmp file. You can then use WinDbg to analyse the cause of the crash. Step-by-step instructions can be found [here](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/49515).