# How to detect the cause of what causes Windows Explorer to crash?

Tags: windows-explorer

I see you have succussfully answered this question previously but it is not specific to my system.  I have downloaded your file and created the relevant dump file but I don't know how to analyse it. Can I upload it to you for some advice please?

Comment: Which previous question are you referring to?

Comment: @Xavierjazz I think the user means me, I've answered several questions in the past about this.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring specifically to the post found here; https://superuser.com/questions/524263/windows-explorer-crashes-whenever-opening-a-usb-or-network-drive

Answer (score 11):

To diag a Windows Explorer crash, you need to generate a crash dump first. You can use the Windows Error Reporting service for this since Vista SP1.

> Starting with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with Service Pack
>   1 (SP1), Windows Error Reporting (WER) can be configured so that full
>   user-mode dumps are collected and stored locally after a user-mode
>   application crashes. Applications that do their own custom crash
>   reporting, including .NET applications, are not supported by this
>   feature.

To configure Windows Error Reporting, you have a few options. You can follow the [steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx) written by Microsoft or just [import my .reg file](https://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU). Alternatively you can use [procdump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump):

```
procdump -mp explorer.exe -i C:\explorer_dumps\
```

All of the above just configure Windows to write a dump file whenever explorer.exe crashes. Now wait for explorer to crash again.

To analyze this crash dump or memory dump (.dmp) from a bugcheck/BSOD, you need to [install Windbg](http://windbg.xyz/article/view/1), which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

[image]

- Run `windbg.exe (x86)` (if you use a 32Bit Windows) or `windbg.exe (x64)` (if you use a 64Bit Windows)
- Inside Windbg.exe, click on `file`->`Open crash dump` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>> and open the generated dump file (.dmp).
- After you loaded the dmp inside Windbg.exe, click on `file`->`Symbol File Path` and configure [Windg to use debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046):

  `SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`
- now type `!analyze -v` in the command box at buttom and press `ENTER`:

  [image]
  Now Windbg load the debug symbols and analyses the dump. Look here for 3rd party DLLs [like in my example here](https://superuser.com/a/1102334/174557) where `psdprotect.dll` causes the crash.

Comment: Thank you for this information.  I have generated the dump file and zipped it.  I am using Windows 7 though so am unsure if I can download this windbg.exe file to attempt debugging myself.

Comment: should be able to use Windbg in windows 7.  if you need help, upload the zipped dump (onedrive, dropbox) and post the share link here

Comment: @magicandre1981 Excellent answer. It would be good if you were to write a *canonical question and answer* about analysing dmp files, combining this with your other answer. Can you consider doing this please?

Comment: @DavidPostill what should I do? ‍♂️