# Windows Explorer is crashing whenever I open Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

This is the link to my zipped dump file, any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/64ed3c820lee72y/explorer.exe.2208.7z?dl=0

Comment: I [told you here how to debug it](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557). Post the dump there and not in a new question.

Comment: Actually you didn't say any such thing.  You told me the name of a debug program (for windows10) nothing more.  Following that link just left me totally confused. As for the upload info, you simply said upload it here followed by a link to a webpage to post new questions.

Comment: I posted a large answer with all required steps to debug a dmp. Also apply my [uninstall.reg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/69dxy4bahgvutug/WER_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg?dl=1) to disable app verifier. Also if my reply helped, [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: any update? have you updated the driver?

Comment: Pauline, in general if you have more information to add to an existing question, even one that has answers posted but which has not yet been solved, the correct action is to continue to edit that answer. The goal is to have a complete question and a good answer contained within a single, easy to navigate and follow, page. When asked to upload your logs on your own question, the assumption should always be that we'd like you to use that EDIT button to link those logs right there on the same question.

Answer (score 2):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg.exe as I told you yesterday](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557) shows me that the Realtek Audio driver DLL `RtkAPO.dll` causes he crash:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_LOCKS_LOCK_IN_FREED_HEAP (202)
Freeing heap block containing an active critical section.
This stop is generated if a heap allocation contains a critical section,
the allocation is freed and the critical section has not been deleted.
To debug this stop use the following debugger commands:
$ !cs -s parameter1 - dump information about this critical section.
$ ln parameter1 - to show symbols near the address of the critical section.
This should help identify the leaked critical section.
$ dps parameter2 - to dump the stack trace for this critical section initialization.
$ parameter3 and parameter4 might help understand where this heap block was
allocated (the size of the allocation is probably significant). 
Arguments:
Arg1: 0790d83c, Critical section address. Run !cs -s <address> to get more information. 
Arg2: 00db2e6c, Critical section initialization stack trace. Run dps <address> to dump the stack trace. 
Arg3: 0790d4d0, Heap block address. 
Arg4: 000020f8, Heap block size. 
Cannot find frame 0x12, previous scope unchanged
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12002.

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=00000002 ebx=0790d4d0 ecx=001a1da0 edx=001a1da0 esi=0559f040 edi=6fcc40c0
eip=6fcac0de esp=03474404 ebp=0347461c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00200202
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x5ce:
6fcac0de cc              int     3
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+5ce
6fcac0de cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 6fcac0de (verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x000005ce)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 85352030
   Parameter[2]: 001a1da0

BUGCHECK_STR:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

CRITICAL_SECTION:  0790d83c -- (!cs -s 0790d83c)

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

SUITE_MASK:  272

DUMP_FLAGS:  c07

DUMP_TYPE:  3

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_LOADED: 1

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  ENA

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n309]
    Type:   [@APPLICATION_FAULT_STRING]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Add
            String: [BREAKPOINT]
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

    ID:     [0n92]
    Type:   [AVRF]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x8a0]
    TID:    [0x950]
    Frame:  [0] : verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 6fcb98e8 to 6fcac0de

STACK_TEXT:  
0347461c 6fcb98e8 6fcc40c0 00000202 0790d83c verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x5ce
03474650 6fcb3e4c 00000000 0790d4d0 000020f8 verifier!AVrfpFreeMemLockChecks+0xd0
03474674 6fcbcbff 00000000 0790d4d0 000020f8 verifier!AVrfpFreeMemNotify+0x2b
034746c0 772e98cd 00860000 00000000 0790d4d0 verifier!AVrfpRtlFreeHeap+0x36
0347470c 6fcbd61f 0790d4d0 6de7070d 00000000 msvcrt!free+0xcd
03474740 6513895a 0790d4d0 0790d4d0 03474764 verifier!AVrfp_delete+0x2c
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03474750 651382f8 00000001 00000001 00000001 RtkAPO+0x8895a
03474764 05d27a3f 0790d4d0 6423eed1 074a4f68 RtkAPO+0x882f8
03474830 05db022e 00000000 05e102f8 00000000 ALSNDMGR!CPlApplet+0x341f
03474840 05d23a13 00000000 6423e1f5 00000000 ALSNDMGR!CPlApplet+0x8bc0e
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ALSNDMGR+0x3a13


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  128245e1c5a144067c7294143b1d70e44a9ee3fa

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  35e2a119c101d670bb94135875c4d22686f3a219

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  a972caf98c89a7775743fa4131f66224f77c3960

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
RtkAPO+8895a
6513895a 59              pop     ecx

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  5ec68b59

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  rtkapo+8895a

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: RtkAPO

IMAGE_NAME:  RtkAPO.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  494f46bb

STACK_COMMAND:  ~5s ; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF_rtkapo+8895a

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80000003

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  RtkAPO.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  RtkAPO.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  RtkAPO

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  RtkAPO

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  Unknown

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  Unknown

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  8895a

BUCKET_ID_MODPRIVATE: 1

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  494f46bb

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  26d77a

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  11.0.6000.85

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BREAKPOINT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  RtkAPO.dll!Unknown

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF_80000003_RtkAPO.dll!Unknown

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/explorer.exe/6.1.7601.23537/57c44cc4/verifier.dll/6.1.7600.16385/4a5bdb2a/80000003/0000c0de.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2017-07-20T21:46:36.000Z

OSBUILD:  7601

OSSERVICEPACK:  23392

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt (Service Pack 1) SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-03-17 23:29:12

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160317-0600

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_ldr

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.23392

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  ef94

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:breakpoint_avrf_80000003_rtkapo.dll!unknown

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c97b21a6-fb5d-c17e-e29a-6d8fa44dca70}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0:005> !cs -s 0790d83c
-----------------------------------------
Critical section   = 0x0790d83c (+0x790D83C)
DebugInfo          = 0x05772518
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000


Stack trace for DebugInfo = 0x05772518:

0x77566cd0: ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx+0xB3
0x7756ed1c: ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount+0x19
0x6fcb8fc0: verifier!AVrfpInitializeCriticalSectionCommon+0xD8
0x6fcb90f9: verifier!AVrfpRtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x11
0x65137b05: RtkAPO+0x87B05
0x65138255: RtkAPO+0x88255
0x6513b5d6: RtkAPO+0x8B5D6
0x651338a7: RtkAPO+0x838A7
0x75ce8c66: ole32!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance+0x172
0x75d03128: ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0x108
0x75ce8d8a: ole32!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance+0x112
0x75ce8cff: ole32!CProcessActivator::CCICallback+0x6D
0x75ce8a82: ole32!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation+0x2C
0x75ce8a33: ole32!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext+0x4F
0x75ce8ded: ole32!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance+0x49
0x75d03128: ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0x108
0x75d02eac: ole32!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance+0xB0
0x75d03128: ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0x108
0x75d03050: ole32!ICoCreateInstanceEx+0x404
0x75d09dd5: ole32!CComActivator::DoCreateInstance+0xD9
0:005> lmvm RtkAPO
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
650b0000 6531c000   RtkAPO     (export symbols)       RtkAPO.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: RtkAPO.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\RtkAPO.dll
    Image name: RtkAPO.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon Dec 22 08:50:19 2008 (494F46BB)
    CheckSum:         0026D77A
    ImageSize:        0026C000
    File version:     11.0.6000.85
    Product version:  11.0.6000.85
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
    ProductName:      Realtek(r) LFX/GFX DSP component
    InternalName:     RTKAPODll
    OriginalFilename: RTKAPO.Dll
    ProductVersion:   11, 0, 6000, 85
    FileVersion:      11, 0, 6000, 85
    FileDescription:  Realtek(r) LFX/GFX DSP component
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (c) Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 2008
```

The driver is from 2008, so very old. Update the Realtek driver or delete the `ALSNDMGR.cpl` from `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` to fix it.

Comment: Well I have absolutely no idea how that was revealed to you amongst all that gobbeldy gook but if getting a new audio driver will fix things then I thank you for your most valued time Sir.

Comment: He used windbg and analyzed the dump file, RtkAPO.dll, is the offending dll which is a Realtek Audio file.  It's the only file listed.

Comment: @Ramhound I've link my answer from yesterday where I posted all steps. I have no idea what else I should post ‍♂️

Comment: @magicandre1981 You shouldn't have to submit anything else your answer is crystal clear