# BSOD: Page Fault in nonpaged area File: cdd.dll

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I'm running windows 10 build 14393 on a laptop.

Some backstory: I've been getting very frequent BSODs with the error being "kernel security check failure"- about once every 2 days. I think I finally narrowed the issue down to being caused by my new usb 3 hub. I unplugged the hub and got no BSODs for about a week- at least until today.

Today I got a BSOD but instead the error was "Page Fault in nonpaged area" (a message that I've never seen on this computer before). The file concerned was cdd.dll. What could be causing this type of BSOD?

My ram is new (got it around the same time as the USB hub- 2 months ago). However, this is the first time I've gotten the page fault error message in the 2 months with the new ram, and the "kernel security check failure" errors kept occurring when I put the old ram in as a test. Memtest also completed 1 pass fine. Other than that, no hardware has been "changed" per-se, but I did open my laptop and put it back together to replace the screen which had broken.

**If you'd like to read the above paragraphs in bullet form:**

- 2 months ago: Replaced screen
- 2 months ago: Changed RAM
- 1.6 months ago: Started using new USB hub
- 1.5 months ago: Started getting BSODs "Kernel security check failure" fairly regularly.
- 1 month ago: Put the old ram back in
- 1 month ago: Memtest completed successfully
- 1 month ago: Continued to receive kernel security check failure BSODs
- 1 week ago: Stopped using USB hub
- 1 week ago: stopped receiving kernel security check failure BSOD
- Today: got a BSOD "page fault in nonpaged area" with the file being cdd.dll
- Today: chkdsk completed succesfully

Comment: A quick Google search lists faulty hardware or software being the cause of a "page fault in nonpaged area" BSOD. The most common hardware is RAM. It'll be painful, but try removing one RAM chip at a time and testing that way. Memtest can't catch everything.

Comment: yeah, I saw that. That's why I ran the old ram in it for a week, and mentioned that this is the first BSOD of it's type i've gotten having had the ram for 2 months

Comment: also seemed like the problem can refer to a ram issue, but if a file is listed (like cdd.dll), it could mean that the issue was only in ram because that driver called it?

Comment: Unless I'm mis-reading, you have not reinstalled the new RAM. Perhaps there's an issue with your old RAM?

Comment: I assume the output of your analysis with windbg confirms the failure is with cdd.dll file?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I have reinstalled the new ram

Comment: @Ramhound not sure what windbg is, but WhoCrashed shows cdd.dll

Comment: WhoCrashed also (for whatever reason) has decided that "This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem"

Comment: WhoCrashed is notorious for pointing you to the wrong reason for a crash.  The only reliable method I have seen over the years is using windbg to do an analysis on the crash.  [This analysis you perform, will point you to the correct device driver file, if it is indeed a driver causing the problem.](https://superuser.com/questions/1231764/windows-explorer-is-crashing-when-i-access-usb-drive/1233294#1233294)  The crash being caused by cdd.dll based on my research does not make any sense considering the version of Windows your using.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, I was a bit puzzled by it. I'll give windbg a look!

Comment: share the dmp files if windbg is too complicated

Comment: @Ramhound alright, analyzed it with windbg, but I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. The only potentially helpful thing I see is "ntoskrnl.wrong.symbols.exe" or similar popping up everywhere and I still don't know what that means. ntoskrnl.exe was what most of the Kernel security check failure blue screens complained about, but that's not very helpful considering it's just saying "somewhere in the windows kernel"

Comment: your debug symbol configuration is incorrect. [setup them up correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046)

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately, today it crashed again with "Kernel security check failure". I'm not adept enough with windbg, so here's the crash file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8wPABZ2CJFGQkczNDFlU3A0T0k/view?usp=sharing