# system properties/explorer crashing - ntdll.dll

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, dll

Every time I open System Properties explorer crashes. I'm working on getting Windbg to get a better reason behind it but here is the Event Viewer log for now.

> Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.1.7601.23537, time stamp: 0x57c44efe
>   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23915, time stamp: 0x59b94ee4
>   Exception code: 0xc0000374
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000000bf3e2
>   Faulting process id: 0x1218
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d353bbc088d711
>   Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id: 0f8b0361-bfaf-11e7-a61c-101f74c6c2a1

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0jpe5cmz80zd0t/Report.wer?dl=0) to the "Report.wer" Whatever that is.

I just checked the event viewer again and ntdll.dll has been causing problems with not only explorer but "DllHost.exe", "Fuel.Service.exe"(AMD Graphics related) and "HPSFUpdater.exe" Other than that I've been having this error about my Bluetooth adapter that could be related

> Faulting application name: CsrBtOBEXService.exe, version: 2.1.63.0, time stamp: 0x4f68683b
>   Faulting module name: CsrBtOBEXService.exe, version: 2.1.63.0, time stamp: 0x4f68683b
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000006f58
>   Faulting process id: 0x6ac
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d35049edb6d03b
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack\CsrBtOBEXService.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack\CsrBtOBEXService.exe
>   Report Id: 85cedec4-bc54-11e7-85a6-101f74c6c2a1

I have tried sfc scan and chkdsk and didn't do anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S. I just found out I can't even download the Windbg because ntdll.dll won't let me install Visual Studio!

Comment: So the first step, and something that you must do if you want to solve your problem, remove the Harmony software you have installed on your system.

Comment: 0xc0000374 = STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION. you need to apply [app verifier](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtziW2MYxY8SglqCKUAszY8GAaE4). with my .reg file you get crash dumps in C:\localdumps. copy them to a second PC and [analyze them here with windbg](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557)

Comment: @Ramhound, I just did that and nothing seemed to change, I also just found out that I can't open AMD Catalyst anymore due to the same issue with everything else.

Comment: @magicandre1981 To be completely honest all of that sounded like jibberish to me but you seem to be asking to use winbg and app verifier, I said in the "P.S" statement that ntdll.dll won't let me download visual studio which is what i believe installs winbg or something like that. Either way I know i need visual studio to get winbg which i can't download. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: use an USB drive with portable 3rd party file manager and only copy the dmps to the drive and analyze it on 2nd PC.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was outdated graphics, I updated it along with a bunch of others and I haven't seen a problem since. Thank you for your support and to who ever else is having this annoying issue I wish you the best of luck.