# Windows Explorer stops working windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a new Lenovo computer and windows explorer stops working from time to time, I have windows 10.

This is the XML log of the error:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-11-07T13:02:52.128724600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3226</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>DEVELOPER.w2d.sub.de</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data>10.0.15063.674</Data> 
  <Data>d8364343</Data> 
  <Data>unknown</Data> 
  <Data>0.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>00000000</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>00000000073c0fd8</Data> 
  <Data>b48</Data> 
  <Data>01d357c64cfa379f</Data> 
  <Data>C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data>unknown</Data> 
  <Data>354346ba-4d07-4316-8f12-eda67d12a656</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: [create a crash dump and analyze the dump with windbg](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557) to see what causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be caused by some reasons.

1. Restart explorer.exe in Task Manager.
2. Update your current video driver
3. Run System File Checker (SFC) to check your files
4. Scan your PC for Virus or Malware infections
5. Start your PC in a Clean Boot environment and troubleshoot the issue
6. Test for picture files that may contain corruption

The link below is about Windows Explorer has stopped working for Windows 7, also it is suit for Windows 10. It includes detailed information for steps.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2694911/error-windows-explorer-has-stopped-working