# Internet Explorer Inoperable after Meltdown/Spectre Patches in Windows 10

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10-v1709, patch, meltdown, spectre

[image]

This started happening shortly after Meltdown/Spectre was in the news. I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling IE.
- Resetting IE settings
- Uninstalling [KB4056892](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892/windows-10-update-kb4056892).

Searching yields results for AMD processor PCs having boot problems, but I'm on an Intel and have no other noticeable symptoms. I'm on Win 10 Enterprise (1709 build 16299.125).

Comment: You don’t even have the Spectre/Meltdown patch installed, are you sure, you actually installed it?

Comment: Can you launch IE11 in safe mode?  http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln265764/how-to-run-microsoft-internet-explorer-in-safe-mode?lang=en hopefully you will respond nicely to both my comments.

Comment: I can confirm IE11 works flawlessly on 16299.248

Comment: [create crash dumps](https://pastebin.com/VDDuMrgb) and [analyze the dumps in Windbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/analyzing-a-user-mode-dump-file-with-windbg) as I [showed for Explorer.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557)

Comment: [Reset Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings).

Comment: @Ramhound "c:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff didn't have any effect. It still crashed.

Comment: Resetting internet explorer settings wasn't helpful either. I did try that before, but forgot to add it to the description.

Comment: @Dzejms - So update your question.  So the noisy comments can be deleted.

Comment: have you created dumps and looked at them?

Comment: I tried but it failed when attempting to modify the registry:
Registry Editor

Cannot import C:\Users\...\...\WER_InternetExplorer.reg: The specified file is not a registry script.
You can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor.

Comment: hm, wired. worked until 1709. open regedit.exe, go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps** create a new key called **iexplore.exe**. Create a string **DumpFolder** that points a folder on your drive (I use C:\localdumps). Now create a 32bit DWORD called DumpType and set it to 2.

Comment: @Ramhound ieframe.dll had some issue. Googled it and found sfc /scannow. After I ran that, it worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open and admin cmd window and issue the following command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow
```

I received the following results:

```
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired
them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.
```

After that, IE launched without issue.
The command was obtained from this post: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/ie10-wont-open-ieframedll-error-pops-on-startup/9c6a60d8-8769-4d98-9f61-11cc99e750c5

Thanks to @Ramhound for walking me through the debug process where ieframe.dll was listed as one of the faulting modules.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall IE and then reinstall it:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type *programs*, and select *Add or remove programs*.
- Select *Turn Windows features on or off*.
- Clear the box for *Internet Explorer 11*.
- After uninstallation completes (reboot may be needed), *check* the box for *Internet Explorer 11*) and complete reinstallation.

[image: Reinstall IE]

That said, [IE11 is deprecated, and Microsoft would prefer you use Edge,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) , whether or not it meets your needs.

Comment: I performed these steps and it did not help. I use IE to test web site changes since a small percentage of my users still use IE. I use Chrome :)

Comment: IE11 isn't deprecated.  Microsoft just recently as this week, continues to fix issues with IE11, they have not announced an EOS (End of Support) for IE11 at this time for Windows 10 either.