# explorer.exe crashes. Need help reading Dumpfile

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, dump

A user has the problem, that when he opens the windows explorer it crashes sometimes (it closes the explorer-window as soon as it opens without a message). Most times this crashes happens a few times in a row until the explorer finally stays open and then the problem is gone for a while.

I not get any usefull information out of the event viewer so I created a memory dump file with this registry entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\explorer.exe]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,43,00,72,00,61,00,73,00,68,00,44,00,75,\
00,6d,00,70,00,73,00,00,00
```

(I got the information about this from here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/appcrash-explorerexe/9cd5009d-f85e-4cce-9ce7-b08adce99e04)

I have 4 dumpfiles now but I can't get any usefull information out of it / can't find the problem. Anyone see something in this dump that could help me find the problem?

(dump is too long to paste it here, that's why I use pastebin: https://pastebin.com/GKuTLfUM

Comment: analyze the crash dump with Windbg as I wrote here: https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 nice writeup. I found that a tool named WinZip was involved. I deinstalled it and will see if that helps. Again, nice writeup and thanks for the hint!