# Video editing software crashes in ntdll.dll

Tags: windows-10, drivers, video, crash, video-editing

I have tried several different video editing applications, and they all crash either when scrubbing through the timeline or rendering the output video. I have tried many things to stop the crashes, but I am out of ideas.

**Software Tried:**

- DaVinci Resolve 15
- Adobe Premiere Elements 2019
- Corel VideoStudio 2018
- VEGAS Pro 15.0

**Workflow:**

- Uninstall video driver and re-install
- Ensure all other drivers are up-to-date
- "Clean boot" (disable all non-Microsoft services and startup programs)
- Ensure Windows is updated

**Computer hardware:**

- Dell Latitude 3480
- Intel Core i5-7300U
- 8 GB RAM
- Windows 10 Pro
- 256 GB SSD
- Intel HD Graphics 620

**Driver versions:**

All drivers were installed via Dell's auto-detection, which now says that everything is up-to-date.

- Graphics: Intel 24.20.100.6286
- SATA RAID controller: 15.2.2.1030
- Intel Display Audio: 10.25.0.10
- Chipset: 10.1.1.38
- Realtek: 6.0.1.8555

**Event Viewer:**

The Windows Event Viewer always points to ntdll.dll, regardless of which program crashes:

```
Faulting application name: Resolve.exe, version: 15.2.3.15, time stamp: 0x5c488f91
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17134.556, time stamp: 0x74bed8b0
Exception code: 0xc000000d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000108580
Faulting process id: 0x2478
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4bbe9d1595e39
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Resolve.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 493d284f-aa75-4ed9-bd2a-6fdea7e00d9c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Dump file:**

I generated a crash dump file from DaVinci Resolve and [opened it in Windbg](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/994423).

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\ProgramData\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Support\logs\Resolve.exe.9336.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 17134 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sun Feb  3 10:10:05.000 2019 (UTC - 8:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:13:24.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
..............................
Loading unloaded module list
........
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(2478.103c): Unknown exception - code c000000d (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter+0x48:
00007ff9`58368580 eb00            jmp     ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter+0x4a (00007ff9`58368582)

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0:000> .reload
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
..............................
Loading unloaded module list
........
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for FairlightPage.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for FairlightPage.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for Resolve.exe - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for igc64.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for igdrcl64.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for OpenCL.DLL - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for pthreadVC2.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for pthreadVC2.dll - 
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12030.

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1

Timeline: !analyze.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2019-02-05T14:47:17.159Z
    Diff: 160632159 mSec

Timeline: Dump.Current
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2019-02-03T18:10:05.0Z
    Diff: 0 mSec

Timeline: Process.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2019-02-03T17:56:41.0Z
    Diff: 804000 mSec


DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  0000000000000018 -- (.cxr 0x18)
Unable to read context, Win32 error 0n30
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter+48
00007ff9`58368580 eb00            jmp     ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter+0x4a (00007ff9`58368582)

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  000000c33d1fa6c0 -- (.exr 0xc33d1fa6c0)
ExceptionAddress: fffffffffffffff8
   ExceptionCode: a0000000
  ExceptionFlags: 3fdaaaaa
NumberParameters: 0

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_PARAMETER

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000000d - An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000000d - An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c000000d

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5c488f91

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  15.2.3.15

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  DaVinci Resolve

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  ntdll.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  74bed8b0

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  108580

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  10.0.17134.556

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  674108b087163da9e8ab7ce37f9f1fe8a36e5120

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  5b1d665f83559cb5c5bef4c9281d6a541dc3550d

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

DUMP_FLAGS:  94

DUMP_TYPE:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  unknown

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  MAGNESIUM

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  02-05-2019 06:47:17.0159

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17763.132 amd64fre

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  ENU

BUGCHECK_STR:  INVALID_PARAMETER

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_PARAMETER

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n321]
    Type:   [@APPLICATION_FAULT_STRING]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Add
            String: [INVALID_PARAMETER]
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

    ID:     [0n97]
    Type:   [@SHUTDOWN]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x2478]
    TID:    [0x103c]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ff95831787f to 00007ff958368580

STACK_TEXT:  
000000c3`3d1f9220 00007ff9`5831787f : 00007ff8`e9affb38 000000c3`3d1f0000 00000000`ffffffff 0000028e`9dfbb830 : ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter+0x48
000000c3`3d1f9300 00007ff9`569fab5a : 0000028f`08acab58 0000028e`9dfbb7e8 00000000`000003e8 0000028f`08acab40 : ntdll!TpAllocTimer+0x5ebaf
000000c3`3d1f9340 00007ff9`3819509d : 0000028f`08acab58 0000028e`9dfbb7e8 00000000`000003e8 00007ff9`58276ff8 : kernel32!CreateThreadpoolTimerStub+0x1a
000000c3`3d1f9370 00007ff9`1cb7c8c6 : 00000000`00000000 0000028e`9dfbb7e8 00000000`00000000 00000000`000003e8 : msvcr120!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for+0xed
000000c3`3d1f9430 00007ff8`e8c4a66d : 00007ff8`e9afe660 0000028e`c648ad88 00007ff8`e9afe670 00007ff9`1cb7ce1d : msvcp120!do_wait+0x7e
000000c3`3d1f94a0 00007ff8`e8c4a446 : 00007ff8`e9afe6d0 00007ff8`e8b049cf 00007ff8`e9afe660 00007ff8`e9afe660 : FairlightPage!GetDLLUIInterface+0x7280d
000000c3`3d1f9510 00007ff8`e8c7a904 : 00007ff8`e9afe660 00007ff8`e9afe5e8 00000000`000003e8 00000000`00000001 : FairlightPage!GetDLLUIInterface+0x725e6
000000c3`3d1f9570 00007ff8`e8f3407a : 00007ff8`e9afe5e8 00007ff8`e9afd210 00000000`00000001 0000028e`faf4a2c8 : FairlightPage!GetDLLUIInterface+0xa2aa4
000000c3`3d1f95b0 00007ff8`e93e7cd4 : 00007ff8`e9afd210 00007ff8`8b05b271 00000000`00000001 00000000`76d1bd60 : FairlightPage!GetDLLUIInterface+0x35c21a
000000c3`3d1f95f0 00007ff8`e93e7f56 : 00000000`00000001 000000c3`3d1f9a80 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`e93e7e34 : FairlightPage!GetDLLUIInterface+0x80fe74
000000c3`3d1f9630 00007ff9`5829b583 : 00000000`7ffe0385 00000000`00000000 00000000`7ffe0384 00000000`7ffe0385 : FairlightPage!GetDLLUIInterface+0x8100f6
000000c3`3d1f9670 00007ff9`582a7f85 : 0000028e`faf79670 00007ff8`e8910000 00007ff8`00000000 00007ff8`e93eca90 : ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x6b
000000c3`3d1f96e0 00007ff9`582a7e48 : 00007ff9`583bbe80 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess+0x125
000000c3`3d1f97e0 00007ff9`569fc80a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000000c3`3d1f9a80 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0xd8
000000c3`3d1f98e0 00007ff9`381b29a7 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 2e74726f`70655268 646e6553`6f747541 : kernel32!ExitProcessImplementation+0xa
000000c3`3d1f9910 00007ff7`87ebd340 : 00007ff9`3826c560 00000000`00000000 0000028f`00000000 0000028f`08554cf0 : msvcr120!doexit+0x1c7
000000c3`3d1f9980 00007ff7`87ebc24a : 00000000`00000080 0000028e`d3414ec0 0000028f`0893a110 0000028e`d3414ec0 : Resolve+0x140d340
000000c3`3d1f9bf0 00007ff9`54a8bdd0 : 00000000`00000000 000000c3`3d1ffe40 00000000`00000000 00007ff9`582683d0 : Resolve+0x140c24a
000000c3`3d1f9c20 00007ff9`58303167 : 00007ff9`3825928c 00007ff9`5839bf54 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x190
000000c3`3d1f9d30 00007ff9`582eb5e6 : 000000c3`3d1fa3d0 00007ff7`885b1839 000000c3`3d1fa500 000000c3`3d1fa9f0 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0+0x38
000000c3`3d1f9d60 00007ff9`582ff7dd : 00000000`00000000 000000c3`3d1f9f00 000000c3`3d1fa500 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!_C_specific_handler+0x96
000000c3`3d1f9dd0 00007ff9`5826d856 : 000000c3`3d1f9f00 000000c3`3d1fa500 00007ff9`56a8ab1c 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
000000c3`3d1f9e00 00007ff9`582fe70e : 000000c3`3d1fa6c0 00000000`00000018 0000028f`08b67e30 00007ff9`4cdb4b84 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x3c6
000000c3`3d1fa500 00007ff9`4ca693a8 : 000000c3`3d1fba20 0000028f`0adc5eb8 0000028f`0adbfba8 0000028e`bbfd1118 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
000000c3`3d1fac80 00007ff9`4ca6ee13 : 000000c3`3d1fba00 000000c3`3d1fba20 0000028f`0840e060 00007ff9`4c56e634 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x269608
000000c3`3d1fb9f0 00007ff9`4ca6dc38 : 0000028f`08119620 0000028e`be184e48 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x26f073
000000c3`3d1fbb60 00007ff9`4ca6f849 : 0000028f`08119600 0000028f`08b67e30 0000028f`08119600 00000000`00000003 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x26de98
000000c3`3d1fbd40 00007ff9`4cc77dc4 : 00000000`00000000 0000028f`08119600 0000028e`aeb44300 00000000`00000000 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x26faa9
000000c3`3d1fbda0 00007ff9`4cc77f23 : 0000028e`be184e88 00000000`00000001 0000028e`aeb44418 00000000`00000000 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x478024
000000c3`3d1fbe70 00007ff9`4cc78143 : 00000000`00000000 0000028e`aeb444e0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x478183
000000c3`3d1fbea0 00007ff9`4cc77849 : 0000028f`00000023 00000000`00000000 000000c3`3d1fc350 0000028e`aeb443e0 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x4783a3
000000c3`3d1fbf70 00007ff9`4c5ab13c : 000000c3`3d1fc358 000000c3`3d1fc0c0 000000c3`3d1fc540 00000000`00000000 : igc64!getJITVersion+0x477aa9
000000c3`3d1fbfc0 00007ff9`4c5ab3de : 000000c3`3d1fc3a0 00007ff9`4c54a9dc 0000028e`aeb44888 000000c3`3d1fc3a0 : igc64!GTPIN_IGC_OCL_UpdateKernelInfo+0x1cdbc
000000c3`3d1fc300 00007ff9`4c548041 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 0000028e`c5e9ef40 0000028f`0a0cfca0 : igc64!GTPIN_IGC_OCL_UpdateKernelInfo+0x1d05e
000000c3`3d1fc350 00007ff9`4c557731 : 00007ff8`ed0a9680 0000028e`c5e9e970 0000028e`eb7c9010 0000028e`b49c0510 : igc64+0x58041
000000c3`3d1fcd10 00007ff8`ed39b6eb : 00007ff9`4c5579b0 00007ff9`4c5579b0 000000c3`3d1fdfa0 0000028e`c5e9ef10 : igc64!CIFCreateMain+0xf11
000000c3`3d1fde70 00007ff8`ed392418 : 00007ff8`ed0af550 000000c3`3d1fe000 0000028e`b49c10e0 0000028e`b49c0510 : igdrcl64!clGetGLContextInfoKHR+0x17e4b
000000c3`3d1fdf00 00007ff8`ed258222 : 0000028e`c5e5e510 0000028e`a0eba028 0000028e`a0eba028 0000028e`aae971f0 : igdrcl64!clGetGLContextInfoKHR+0xeb78
000000c3`3d1fe0f0 00007ff8`ed2164f4 : 00000000`00000000 5651c891`00aaacfe 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : igdrcl64!GTPin_Init+0x36202
000000c3`3d1fe2b0 00007ff8`ffbc2245 : 00000000`00000001 0000028e`ebb25380 000000c3`3d1fe3d0 000000c3`3d1fe3c0 : igdrcl64!clBuildProgram+0x64
000000c3`3d1fe320 00007ff7`8acc23f6 : 0000028e`c5e5e510 00000000`00000001 000000c3`3d1fe490 00000000`00000000 : OpenCL!clBuildProgram+0x65
000000c3`3d1fe360 00007ff7`8acc22dd : 00000000`00000001 000000c3`3d1fe4a0 00000000`00000000 cd2ebf92`d485f614 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,DVIP::ColorGradientParams>::save_object_data+0x5d3c6
000000c3`3d1fe460 00007ff7`8acc079c : 000000c3`3d1fe648 000000c3`3d1fe508 0000028e`c5e5e510 00000000`00000000 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,DVIP::ColorGradientParams>::save_object_data+0x5d2ad
000000c3`3d1fe4d0 00007ff7`8acbea28 : 000000c3`3d1fe8e8 0000028e`fb02c8b0 0000028e`9e6a7f10 000000c3`3d1fe8e8 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,DVIP::ColorGradientParams>::save_object_data+0x5b76c
000000c3`3d1fe600 00007ff7`8b6f6d0a : 00000000`00000001 0000028f`08539240 0000028f`08539240 00000000`00000000 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,DVIP::ColorGradientParams>::save_object_data+0x599f8
000000c3`3d1fe830 00007ff7`88b3cba9 : 0000028e`9e6a7fc0 0000028f`08539240 0000028f`08a90100 00000000`00000438 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,DVIP::ColorGradientParams>::save_object_data+0xa91cda
000000c3`3d1fea90 00007ff7`88a4bd41 : 0000028e`c5e9a780 0000028e`faf17f90 0000028e`d21887a0 0000028e`c5e9a5f8 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,ControlPointCollection>::save_object_data+0x12ce49
000000c3`3d1ff290 00007ff7`88823f45 : 0000028f`12a56670 00007ff7`8d081670 00007ff7`8d081670 0000028e`faf17f90 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,ControlPointCollection>::save_object_data+0x3bfe1
000000c3`3d1ff2c0 00007ff7`885b1839 : 00000000`00000000 000000c3`3d1ffd49 00007ff7`8d081670 00007ff7`8d081670 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,tagCrmResParamV13>::save_object_data+0x3888d5
000000c3`3d1ff2f0 00007ff7`885adea9 : 0000028e`faf17f90 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,tagCrmResParamV13>::save_object_data+0x1161c9
000000c3`3d1ffcb0 00007ff8`fe4562ec : 0000028e`ed807320 000000c3`3d1ffd49 00000000`00000000 00007ff9`582683d0 : Resolve!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,tagCrmResParamV13>::save_object_data+0x112839
000000c3`3d1ffce0 00007ff9`381b4f7f : 00000000`00000000 0000028e`ed7ae5e0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : pthreadVC2!sched_get_priority_max+0x4fef
000000c3`3d1ffdb0 00007ff9`381b5126 : 00007ff9`3826cb80 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msvcr120!_callthreadstartex+0x17
000000c3`3d1ffde0 00007ff9`569f3dc4 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msvcr120!_threadstartex+0x102
000000c3`3d1ffe10 00007ff9`582d3691 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
000000c3`3d1ffe40 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0x18 ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  31296e6e63438d8f1b699e816d723aa478d8f2c2

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  4abc121141fd5b78470beea457ef6e34efd873a9

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  d0c08f49653d2204756bf2f37e8232398e9b9f1a

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
msvcr120!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for+ed [f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\concrt\event.cpp @ 628]
00007ff9`3819509d 4885c0          test    rax,rax

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  74c08548

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\concrt\event.cpp

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\concrt\event.cpp

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  628

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  msvcr120!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for+ed

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: msvcr120

IMAGE_NAME:  msvcr120.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  524f83ff

BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_PARAMETER_msvcr120!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for+ed

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c000000d

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  msvcr120.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  msvcr120.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  msvcr120

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  msvcr120

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  ed

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  524f83ff

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  f105d

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  12.0.21005.1

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  INVALID_PARAMETER_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_PARAMETER

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_PARAMETER_c000000d_msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::wait_for

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/unknown/15.2.3.15/5c488f91/ntdll.dll/10.0.17134.556/74bed8b0/c000000d/00108580.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2019-02-03T18:10:05.000Z

OSBUILD:  17134

OSSERVICEPACK:  556

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  256

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180410-1804

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs4_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  1b5ce

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:invalid_parameter_c000000d_msvcr120.dll!concurrency::details::_condition_variable::wait_for

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {71f9686f-f1ca-1281-d1ee-33739ea91a5b}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: What version of the Intel drivers do you have installed?

Comment: @Ramhound The graphics drivers are Intel 24.20.100.6286; SATA RAID controller 15.2.2.1030; Intel Display Audio 10.25.0.10; chipset 10.1.1.38; Realtek 6.0.1.8555. Everything was installed via Dell's auto-detected drivers, which now says that everything is up-to-date.

Comment: Update your question and include that vital information

Comment: Updated question to include driver versions.